# Groovy XmlSlurper appendNode of child content only

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I have the following xml object:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
def xmlObject = slurper.parseText("<root />")

def xmlObject2 = slurper.parseText("<root2><child1>hello</child1><child2>world</child2></root2>")
```

Now, the objective is to have the following XML format:

```
<root>
<root2>
<child1>hello</child1>
<child2>world</child2>
<root2>
</root>
```

If I use appendNode like this:

```
xmlObject.appendNode {
   root2(xmlObject2)
}
```

I would get:

```
<root>
<root2>
<root2>
<child1>hello</child1>
<child2>world</child2>
<root2>
<root2>
</root>
```

I would have 2 root2. How to appendNode of only the child content? Or appendNode without any tag name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add the node as `xmlObject.appendNode(xmlObject2)`? Here is what I've come up with:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
def xmlObject = slurper.parseText("<root />")

def xmlObject2 = slurper.parseText("<root2><child1>hello</child1><child2>world</child2></root2>")

xmlObject.appendNode(xmlObject2)

println XmlUtil.serialize(xmlObject)
```

It produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <root2>
    <child1>hello</child1>
    <child2>world</child2>
  </root2>
</root>
```

Looks like the result you wanted. I hope it helps.